# Read rows in batches from snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In mysql, if I have to read 10 rows at a time, I can write query as

```
select * from foo limit 10, 10
```

then I can go on increasing the offset and read the entire table.

How do I do the same thing in snowflake?

I tried

```
select a, b from (select a, b from foo) tempview where rownum <= 100;
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Snowflake supports a very similar syntax to MySQL, you simply write

```
select * from foo limit 10 offset 10;
```

Checkout the [Snowflake documentation for LIMIT](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/limit.html) for more details and options.

Note - if you want to scan a table like this, for large tables it might not always be the most efficient way, as you'll see some overhead for every query. Iterating over the result in the client might be a better option.

Finally, if you want to iterate over a result of a complex query, and you really want to use the `LIMIT` approach for some reason, you can run your query, and then use [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) to iterate over the result. This way you won't re-run the query multiple times.